# Ubuntu 23.04. Irregular boundaries between the colors in photo

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, colors

I have bought a Lenovo IdeaCentre i3-12 desktop with an onboard Intel UHD graphics 730. Some photos show some grainy and irregular colors in (typically) a high contrast area. E.g. some green and purple areas are seen.

I have dual booted the computer in Windows, and the same photo looks fine there. It looks like the color depth is too low or like a JPG file with a too high compression.

The problem is seen at both 22.04 and 23.04.

I have attached a photo of the screen when the picture is opened in Gimp. When making a screen shot in Ubuntu the problem is not seen (when viewing the screen shot on a Windows afterwards). Also a crop from the original image is attached for comparison. If other people faces the same problem images will look almost the same.

`xwininfo -root` reports `24 bit depth`

`lshw` reports `Alder Lake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 730]`

I am using it for photo editing, and I don't recall my old computer facing this issue. It is both some of my own photos viewed in Gimp, but also online photos viewed in Firefox.

Do I need to install a proprietary Intel driver? If so, how do I do that? Are there any other tweaks somewhere I can use?

**Update**: The image I used here is also online. I just tried to make a "live CD" on a USB stick, booted Ubuntu 23.04 in live mode and checked the image online. Apparently it looks perfect when I am using the Live CD?

[Photo of image viewed in Gimp taken with a phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTNwM.jpg)

[Crop of the original image for comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLYdm.jpg)

Comment: Please update your question with what version of Ubuntu you're using. And maybe include a sample image of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a little bit embarrassing because it was related to the calibration of the display. I had first calibrated using the build-in calibration functionality in Ubuntu. After installing Display CAL I did a proper calibration and the problem disappeared. It also disappeared if I just disabled the color profile *and* rebooted. Just disabling the color profile without reboot didn't change anything.